# Get base class target from std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, std-function

If I store a polymorphic functor in an std::function, is there a way to extract the functor without knowing the concrete type?

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
struct Base {
    //...
    virtual int operator()(int foo) const = 0;
    void setBar(int bar){}
};

struct Derived : Base {
    //...
    int operator()(int foo) const override {}
};

std::function<int(int)> getFunction() {
    return Derived();
}

int main() {
    auto f = getFunction();
    // How do I call setBar() ?
    if (Base* b = f.target<Base>()) {} // Fails: returns nullptr
    else if(Derived* d = f.target<Derived>()) {
        d->setBar(5); // Works but requires Derived type
    }
    std::cout << f(7) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I want the client to be able to provide their own function, and for my handler to use the functionality of the Base if it's available.

The fall back would be of course to just use the abstract base class instead of std::function and clients would implement the ABC interface as they would have pre-C++11:

```
std::shared_ptr<Base> getFunction {
    return std::make_shared<Derived>();
}
```

but I wanted to know if it's possible to create a more flexible and easier to use interface with C++14. It seems all that's missing is a cast inside std::function::target

Comment: Why `operator()` is virtual in this case?

Comment: The class just provides an implementation of an algorithm, so a function syntax seems appropriate. Some algorithms might use additional parameters like "bar" in this example. This is of course all doable with classic polymorphism but I wanted to try to provide an interface that would just as well take a lambda. Another way to do this would be to put all known possible parameters in the function signature, but that would eliminate any partial evaluation.
FWIW the actual code has a named virtual function and an non-virtual operator().

Comment: Class can provide whatever but you define a virtual function and do not use it as a virtual, does that not ring a bell?

Comment: @Slava If NOT using std::function, the virtual is necessary to call generically using a reference to the base class. When using only std::function to store and call the concrete implementation, you're right, it may be superfluous.

Comment: It is not only superfluous, it is the same problem that you do not use virtual function dispatching and you cannot detect base class.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems all that's missing is a cast inside std::function::target

All `target<T>` currently needs is to check `target_id<T> == stored_type_info`.

Being able to cast back to the real (erased) type in a context where that type may not be visible, and then check how it's related to the requested type ... is not really feasible.

Anyway, `std::function` is polymorphic only on the function signature. That's the thing it abstracts. If you want general-purpose polymorphism, just return a `unique_ptr<Base>` and use that.

If you really want `function<int(int)>` for the function-call syntax, instantiate it with a pimpl wrapper for `unique_ptr<Base>`.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution would be to have a thin wrapper:

```
 struct BaseCaller {
     BaseCaller( std::unique_ptr<Base> ptr ) : ptr_( std::move( ptr ) ) {}
     int operator()( int foo ) { return (*ptr)( foo ); }

     std::unique_ptr<Base> ptr_;
 };
```

now user must create all derived from Base classed through this wrapper:

```
std::function<int(int)> getFunction() {
    return BaseCaller( std::make_unique<Derived>() );
}
```

and you check in your call that target is a `BaseCaller`.

Answer (score 0):

> I want the client to be able to provide their own function, and for my handler to use the functionality of the Base if it's available.

The main drawback to using virtual dispatch is that it may create an optimization barrier. For instance, the virtual function calls cannot usually be inlined, and "devirtualization" optimizations are generally pretty difficult for the compiler to actually do in practical situations.

If you are in a situation where the code is performance critical, you can roll your own type-erasure and avoid any vtable / dynamic allocations.

I'm going to follow a pattern demonstrated in an old (but well-known) article, the ["Impossibly Fast Delegates"](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11015/The-Impossibly-Fast-C-Delegates).

```
// Represents a pointer to a class implementing your interface
class InterfacePtr {
  using ObjectPtr = void*;
  using CallOperator_t = int(*)(ObjectPtr, int);
  using SetBar_t = void(ObjectPtr, int);

  ObjectPtr obj_;
  CallOperator_t call_;
  SetBar_t set_bar_;

  // Ctor takes any type that implements your interface,
  // stores pointer to it as void * and lambda functions
  // that undo the cast and forward the call

  template <typename T>
  InterfacePtr(T * t)
    : obj_(static_cast<ObjectPtr>(t))
    , call_(+[](ObjectPtr ptr, int i) { return (*static_cast<T*>(ptr))(i); })
    , set_bar_(+[](ObjectPtr ptr, int i) { static_cast<T*>(ptr)->set_bar(i); })
  {}

  int operator()(int i) {
    return call_(obj_, i);
  }

  void set_bar()(int i) {
    return set_bar_(obj_, i);
  }
};
```

Then, you would take `InterfacePtr` instead of a pointer to `Base` in your API.

If you want the interface member `set_bar` to be optional, then you could use SFINAE to detect whether `set_bar` is present, and have two versions of the constructor, one for when it is, and one for when it isn't. There is recently a really great exposition of the "detection idiom" at various C++ standards on Tartan Llama's blog, [here](https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/detection-idiom/). The advantage of that would be that you get something similar to what `virtual` gives you, with the possibility to optionally override functions, but the dispatch decisions get made at compile-time, and you aren't forced to have a vtable. And all of the functions can potentially be inlined if the optimizer can prove to itself that e.g. in some compilation unit using this, only one type is actually passed to your API through this mechanism.

A difference is that this `InterfacePtr` is non-owning and doesn't have the dtor or own the storage of the object it's pointing to.

If you want `InterfacePtr` to be owning, like `std::function`, and copy the functor into its own memory and take care of deleting it when it goes out of scope, then I'd recommend to use `std::any` to represent the object instead of `void *`, and use `std::any_cast` in the lambdas instead of `static_cast<T*>` in my implementation. There's some good further discussion of `std::any` and why it's good for this usecase on `/r/cpp` [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/7l3i19/why_was_stdany_added_to_c17/).

I don't think there's any way to do what you were originally asking, and recover the "original" functor type from `std::function`. Type erasure erases the type, you can't get it back without doing something squirrelly.

---

Edit: Another alternative you might consider is to use a type-erasure library like [dyno](https://github.com/ldionne/dyno)

Comment: Note that this isn't an owning type, like `std::function` is.

Answer (score 0):

`std::function<X>::target<T>` can only cast back to *exactly* `T*`.

This is because storing how to convert to every type that can be converted to `T*` would require storing more information.  It takes information to convert a pointer-to-derived to a pointer-to-base in the general case in C++.

`target` is intended to simply permit replacing some function-pointer style machinery with `std::function`s and have the existing machinery work, and do so with nearly zero cost (just compare typeids).  Extending that cost to every base type of the stored type would have been hard, so it wasn't done, and won't be free, so it probably won't be done in the future.

`std::function` is, however, just an example of type erasure, and you can roll your own with additional functionality.

The first thing I'd do is I would do away with your `virtual operator()`.  Type-erasure based polymorphism doesn't need that.

The second thing is get your hands on an `any` -- either `boost::any` or [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)'s `std::any`.

That writes the hard part of type erasure -- small buffer optimization and value storage -- for you.

Add to that your own dispatch table.

```
template<class Sig>
struct my_extended_function;
template<class R, class...Args>
struct my_extended_function<R(Args...)> {
  struct vtable {
    R(*f)(any&, Args&&...) = 0;
    void*(*cast)(any&, std::type_info const&) = 0;
  };
  template<class...Bases, class T>
  my_extended_function make_with_bases( T t ) {
    return {
      get_vtable<T, Bases...>(),
      std::move(t)
    };
  }
  R operator()(Args...args)const {
    return (*p_vtable->f)(state, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
private:
  template<class T, class...Bases>
  static vtable make_vtable() {
    vtable ret{
      // TODO: R=void needs different version
      +[](any& ptr, Args&&...args)->R {
        return (*any_cast<T*>(ptr))(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
      },
      +[](any& ptr, std::type_info const& tid)->void* {
        T* pt = any_cast<T*>(ptr);
        if (typeid(pt)==tid) return pt;
        // TODO: iterate over Bases, see if any match tid
        // implicitly cast pt to the Bases* in question, and return it.
      }
    };
  }
  template<class T, class...Bases>
  vtable const* get_vtable() {
    static vtable const r = make_vtable<T,Bases...>();
    return &r;
  }
  vtable const* p_vtable = nullptr;
  mutable std::any state;
  my_extended_function( vtable const* vt, std::any s ):
    p_vtable(vt),
    state(std::move(s))
  {}
};
```